# Add indices unique for each eaddress in a list

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have a big list of emails that link to information and I want each email to have an index:

```
index      email             information
----------------------------------------
1      example@hotmail.com   spam
1      example@hotmail.com   foo
1      example@hotmail.com   bar
2      someone@yahoo.com     baz
2      someone@yahoo.com     bit
3      james@james.com       james
```

How could I assign those indexes to be the same for each row of the same email, but then increment when the email changes?

Answer (score 2):

If `spam` is in C2 then in A2:

```
=IF(B2=B1,A1,A1+1)
```

and copied down might suit, if the eaddresses are first sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case your data is out of order (though you should sort it first as pnuts suggests) and it looks like something like this:

[image: Out of order example]

In cell A2 and copied down is this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B$1:B1,B2)=0,MAX(A$1:A1)+1,INDEX(A$1:A1,MATCH(B2,B$1:B1,0)))
```